# aws opensearch: Why are similar sets of data ranked differently

Tags: amazon-web-services, ranking, opensearch

I have set up an AWS Opensearch instance with pretty much everything set to default values. i then have inserted some data regarding hotels. When the user searches like `Good Morning B` my resulting query `POST` request looks like this:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "good morning b*",
                        "fields": ["name"],
                        "default_operator": "and"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "provider": "SomeProvider"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        },
        "name.keyword": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

The result contains 4 entries with 2 different hotels. The names and all the other data in the index besides the ID are the same. Here is an excerpt of the response:

```json
{
  "took": 442,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "hotels",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 11.143229,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Good Morning + Berlin City East",
          "provider": "SomeProvider"
        },
        "sort": [
          11.143229,
          "Good Morning + Berlin City East"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "hotels",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 10.455675,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Good Morning Bad Oldesloe",
          "provider": "SomeProvider"
        },
        "sort": [
          10.455675,
          "Good Morning Bad Oldesloe"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "hotels",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 10.455675,
        "_source": {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Good Morning Bad Oldesloe",
          "provider": "SomeProvider"
        },
        "sort": [
          10.455675,
          "Good Morning Bad Oldesloe"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "hotels",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 9.6945305,
        "_source": {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Good Morning + Berlin City East",
          "provider": "SomeProvider"
        },
        "sort": [
          9.6945305,
          "Good Morning + Berlin City East"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see that the "Good Morning + Berlin City East" has two different ranks for the entries. Like i said, the containing data is exactly the same. Since the name is the same, i would have expected it to be ranked equally like it is the case for the "Good Morning Bad Oldesloe" hotel.

I ran the same query with the `explain=true` parameter and got this for the Berlin entries (i only post the relevant part here to make it a bit compact):

```json
// ID = 1
{
  "sort": [
    11.143229,
    "Good Morning + Berlin City East"
  ],
  "_explanation": {
    "value": 11.143229,
    "description": "sum of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 9.302926,
        "description": "sum of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 4.151463,
            "description": "weight(name:good in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 4.151463,
                "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2.2,
                    "description": "boost",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 4.811831,
                    "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                    "details": [
                      {
                        "value": 11,
                        "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 1413,
                        "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                        "details": []
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 0.3921644,
                    "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                    "details": [
                      {
                        "value": 1.0,
                        "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 1.2,
                        "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 0.75,
                        "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 5.0,
                        "description": "dl, length of field",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 3.6001415,
                        "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                        "details": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": 4.151463,
            "description": "weight(name:morning in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 4.151463,
                "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 2.2,
                    "description": "boost",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 4.811831,
                    "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                    "details": [
                      {
                        "value": 11,
                        "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 1413,
                        "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                        "details": []
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 0.3921644,
                    "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                    "details": [
                      {
                        "value": 1.0,
                        "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 1.2,
                        "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 0.75,
                        "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 5.0,
                        "description": "dl, length of field",
                        "details": []
                      },
                      {
                        "value": 3.6001415,
                        "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                        "details": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value": 1.0,
            "description": "name:b*",
            "details": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 1.840302,
        "description": "weight(provider:hob in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 1.840302,
            "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 2.2,
                "description": "boost",
                "details": []
              },
              {
                "value": 1.8403021,
                "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 224,
                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1413,
                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 0.45454544,
                "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1.2,
                    "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 0.75,
                    "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "dl, length of field",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

// ID = 2{
  "sort": [
      9.6945305,
      "Good Morning + Berlin City East"
  ],
  "_explanation": {
      "value": 9.6945305,
      "description": "sum of:",
      "details": [
          {
              "value": 7.975009,
              "description": "sum of:",
              "details": [
                  {
                      "value": 3.4875045,
                      "description": "weight(name:good in 380) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                      "details": [
                          {
                              "value": 3.4875045,
                              "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                              "details": [
                                  {
                                      "value": 2.2,
                                      "description": "boost",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 4.0562115,
                                      "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                      "details": [
                                          {
                                              "value": 24,
                                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 1414,
                                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                              "details": []
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 0.39081526,
                                      "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                      "details": [
                                          {
                                              "value": 1.0,
                                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 1.2,
                                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 0.75,
                                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 5.0,
                                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 3.5749645,
                                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                              "details": []
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "value": 3.4875045,
                      "description": "weight(name:morning in 380) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                      "details": [
                          {
                              "value": 3.4875045,
                              "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                              "details": [
                                  {
                                      "value": 2.2,
                                      "description": "boost",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 4.0562115,
                                      "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                      "details": [
                                          {
                                              "value": 24,
                                              "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 1414,
                                              "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                              "details": []
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 0.39081526,
                                      "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                      "details": [
                                          {
                                              "value": 1.0,
                                              "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 1.2,
                                              "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 0.75,
                                              "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 5.0,
                                              "description": "dl, length of field",
                                              "details": []
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "value": 3.5749645,
                                              "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                              "details": []
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "value": 1.0,
                      "description": "name:b*",
                      "details": []
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "value": 1.719521,
              "description": "weight(provider:hob in 380) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details": [
                  {
                      "value": 1.719521,
                      "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                      "details": [
                          {
                              "value": 2.2,
                              "description": "boost",
                              "details": []
                          },
                          {
                              "value": 1.719521,
                              "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                              "details": [
                                  {
                                      "value": 253,
                                      "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 1414,
                                      "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                      "details": []
                                  }
                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              "value": 0.45454544,
                              "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                              "details": [
                                  {
                                      "value": 1.0,
                                      "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 1.2,
                                      "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 0.75,
                                      "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 1.0,
                                      "description": "dl, length of field",
                                      "details": []
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "value": 1.0,
                                      "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                      "details": []
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

The main difference and the cause for the difference in rank seems to be the `n, number of documents containing term` which is 11 in case of the higher ranked id = 1 and 24 in case of the lower ranked id = 2.
But since every data field is the same (besides the id), should'nt it be the same number? The search term is the same for both entries.

Can somebody explain to me (in easy words without much mathematics please) why there is a difference for this hotel but not for the one in Bad Oldesloe (here, as one would expect, the numbers in the explanation has been the same)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of documents is counted not for the whole index by Elasticsearch but by the underlying Lucene engine, and it's done per shard (each shard is a complete Lucene index). Since your documents are (probably) in different shards, their score turns out slightly different.

Comment: Hi ilvar, thanks for your fast response. I will check if this is correct but it already helped me and would explain the behaviour. found this link which further explains the sharding: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-how-many-shards-do-i-need/

Comment: thanks a lot. I found out that the entries with the same rank are in the same shard, the others are in different shards. For those that are interested and have the same problem: When the amount of documents you seen in the "explanation=true" response is different, you can send a request to `_cat/shards/<index-name>?v`. and see in which shard your document is placed by just looking at the amount of documents.